# Printing data to a pre printed form/stationery

Tags: java, image, forms, printing, alignment

We have a requirement where we already have pre printed stationery and want user to put data in a HTML form and be able to print data on that form. Alignment/text size etc are very important since the pre-printed stationery already has boxes for each character. What could be a good way to achieve this in java? I have thinking of using jasper reports. Any other options? May be overlay image with text or something?

Also we might need to capability to print on plain paper in which case the boxes needs to be printed by our application and the form should match after the printed with the already printed blank stationery containing data.

Do we have some open source framework to do such stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem when printing form content that has been filled in electronically, is aligning it correctly on the pre-printed form. You may get content to align for one printer, but when you use another it is completely misaligned.

Fly Software have a form design product called InForm Designer that gets around the problem nicely by allowing users to specify and save vertical and horizontal offsets for printers. This ensures filled in form content is always aligned. I've tried it and it works perfectly. Take a look for yourself here...

http://www.flysoftware.com/products/inform_designer/overview.asp

It might be worth implementing a printer offset similar to InForm's in your own application (if possible).

Answer (score 3):

Jaspersoft reports -- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/

You will then create XML templates, then you will be able to produce a report in PDF, HTML, CSV, XLS, TXT, RTF, and more.  It has all the necessary options to customize the report.  Used it before and recommend it.

You will create the templates with iReport then write the code for the engine to pass the data in different possible ways.

check http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports

Edit:

You can have background images and overlay the boxes over it and set a limit on the max character size ... and many more

It is very powerful and gives you plenty of options

Here is one of iReport's tutorial for a background image http://ireport-tutorial.blogspot.com/2008/12/background-image-in-ireport.html

Comment: Thanks. I would study the tutorial however a quick question if someone is aware of. Will jasper report have an option to use a background image? Then I can scan the pre-printed stationary and put text boxes on top of it. Fill in data and generate HTML report. Hope the HTML output will print well with alignment on all printers as client does not want to use pdf.

Comment: Oh yes.  It is very powerful and will you will have control over everything.  Images\data tables\alignment ..

Answer (score 1):

Some things to think about.
First in terms of the web page, do you want use the stationery as the form layout? 
Does it have to be exact?
Combed boxes (one for each character) 
Do you want to show it like that on the web page, or deal with the combing later.
How are you going to deal with say a combed 6 digit number. Is this right aligned. What if they enter 7 digits. Same for text. what if it won't fit. 
Font choices, we had a lot of fun with W... 
How aligned do you want the character within the box, what font limitations does that imply, some of the auto magic software we looked at did crap like change the size of each character.

Combed editing is a nightmare, we display combed, but raise an edit surface the size of the full box on selection.

Another thing that might drive you barking mad, you find find small differences in the size and layout of the boxes, so they look okay from a distance but a column of boxes sort of shifts about by a pixel. Some of testing guys had to lend us their electron microscopes, so we could see how many ink molecules we were out by. :(

Expect to spend a lot of time in the UI side of things, and remember printed stationery changes, so giving yourself some sort of meta description of the form to start with will save you loads of trouble later on.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I am sure this is going to be a challenging project to handle. Will surely keep your notes in mind. :)

Comment: Did all of this and more, no 3rd party stuff either, except for pdf output. .net and c# for winforms though. Make sure you get a decent scope document on the form input, we ended up with masses of custom controls, because of course that was what we meant and can you justs.